# "lose the weight vs lose weight"

Tags: definite-article

Why the definite article, in fact ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=want%20to%20lose%20the%20weight%2Cwant%20to%20lose%20weight&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=17&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20lose%20the%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwant%20to%20lose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwant%20to%20lose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWant%20to%20Lose%20Weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWant%20to%20lose%20weight%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwant%20to%20lose%20the%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwant%20to%20lose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwant%20to%20lose%20weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWant%20to%20Lose%20Weight%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWant%20to%20lose%20weight%3B%2Cc0)), isn't used with 'lose weight'? Are there also some other words that follow this rule?

> I go jogging because I want to lose **the weight**.
>
> I go jogging because I want to lose **weight**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No article is needed in the idiom, *[to lose weight](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lose+weighthttps://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lose+weight)* because, as the other answer pointed out, no particular weight is stated. So you could understand it as:

> I go jogging because I want to lose ***[some]*** weight.

Your sentence would need an article, only if it were followed by a [restrictive modifying NP or relative clause](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/restrictive_modifier.htm):

> I go jogging because I want to lose ***the*** weight ***I gained in my student years***.

*Note that here, "weight" is [uncountable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/weight).*

There are plenty of other such idioms.
e.g.

> [build confidence](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/build-confidence), [take courage](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-courage-from-something), [make sense](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-sense)

With countable nouns the articles ***a*** or ***the*** can be used:

> [make a mistake](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjV0czlmKbyAhUZiFwKHR-aAAwQFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fidioms.thefreedictionary.com%2Fmake%2Ba%2Bmistake&usg=AOvVaw3Fhzzcdj1jbtavc92Q7aBg), [take a walk](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXrff2mKbyAhXFhVwKHUipDW8QFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.macmillandictionary.com%2Fdictionary%2Fbritish%2Fgo-for-go-on-take-a-walk&usg=AOvVaw2qN3ezhv2gClvCSMI3VMcx), [take the fall](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+the+fall), [miss the boat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi84_qemabyAhVUuXEKHbF9BlgQFnoECB4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.cambridge.org%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fmiss-the-boat&usg=AOvVaw1KrhYX3srj6T7CZgzWndkk)

Answer (score 1):

You go jogging because you want to lose (an unspecified amount of ) weight.

You use the definite article when you refer to a specific weight or the weight of a specific item.

**The weight of the camel's load is too great.**
**The weight he carried exhausted him.**.

**The bearers carried large weights through the pass.**
**The instrument measures weight.**

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to lose weight.
> vs.
> I would like to lose **the** weight.

In the version with the definite article, the weight being spoken of has already been identified as a burden. It may have been mentioned very recently, or it may be a chronic problem for the speaker. Very likely, the person spoken to also knows that *that* weight is a burden to the speaker.